# Two relationships between two tables

Tags: t-sql

So, I have this simple question.
We have two tables: Transactions and Local.

```
+++++++++++
|  Local  |
-----------
|id_local |
|Street   |
|ZIP      |
+++++++++++

+++++++++++++++++
|  Transaction  |
-----------------
|id_trans       |
|id_local_src   |
|id_local_dst   |
+++++++++++++++++
```

Now, I need to make sure that in transactions we record the location (source) and location (destination).
Problem is I can make the relation id_local_src to id_local and id_local_dst to id_local but is this a problem? Because If I want to make this query it does not show me a thing:

```
SELECT id_trans,--How can specify street from and street to?
Street,ZIP
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN Local ON Transactions.id_local_src=Local.id_local AND Transactions.id_local_dst=Local.id_local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [table alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
SELECT id_trans,
    src.Street AS fromStreet,
    src.ZIP AS fromZIP,
    dst.Street AS toStreet,
    dst.ZIP AS toZIP
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN
    Local src ON Transactions.id_local_src = src.id_local INNER JOIN
    Local dst ON Transactions.id_local_dst = dst.id_local
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution

```
SELECT
T.id_trans AS id_trans,
LSRC.Street AS StreetFrom,
LDST.Street AS StreetTo,
LSRC.ZIP AS ZIPFrom,
LDST.ZIP AS ZIPTo

FROM `transaction` AS T

INNER JOIN `local` AS LSRC
ON T.id_local_src = LSRC.id_local

INNER JOIN `local` AS LDST
ON T.id_local_dst = LDST.id_local
```